# The environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api

I am Using Google Speech Client Library in Android with reference link :- https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java

```
I have also executed this command(export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/Users/Downloads/service-account-file.json") in my Mac os

After executing the whole code I am getting this error -->  The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials.
```

Comment: Would you try to fetch the environment variable within your code? My thought is that it's really not set, otherwise you would get a different error.

Comment: how to fetch environment variable in android. ? plz tell me . .....thanks in advance sir